# Words/phrases like "kindred spirit" that refer to both the speaker and the subject of the sentence

Tags: grammar, idioms, terminology

The google definition of kindred spirit is "a person whose interests or attitudes are similar to one's own."

That means that if I were to say to someone "You are a kindred spirit", I am describing them, but them with me as the assumed person being compared to.

I don't have to say "You are a kindred spirit *to me*" or "*You and I* are kindred spirits".

Is there a name for this sort of thing? Are there other examples of words like this?

Comment: "You're a friend" is another example.

Comment: Huh. Interesting. Like a reflexive adjective. Except I just made that up.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on the context, much like "kindered spirit," but:

- chip off the block
- great minds think alike
- cut from the same cloth

These may work.

Comment: Also soul mate.

Comment: The question was not about synonyms for "kindred spirit", but about the construction "You are a kindred spirit."